# MDT 2012 image Failure - Unable to find Imagex.exe

Tags: imaging, mdt

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 with MDT 2012, I installed the Windows 8 ADK before installing MDT 2012. I have created my Deployment Share and set everything up, but when I try to run the build it fails. I have included the error log bellow;

FindFile: The file imagex.exe could not be found in any standard locations. LTIApply    01/06/2015 09:54:30 0 (0x0000)
FAILURE ( 5441 ): 1: FindFile: imagex.exe   LTIApply    01/06/2015 09:54:30 0 (0x0000)
Command completed, return code = -2147467259    LiteTouch   01/06/2015 09:54:30 0 (0x0000)
Litetouch deployment failed, Return Code = -2147467259  0x80004005  LiteTouch   01/06/2015 09:54:30 0 (0x0000)
For more information, consult the task sequencer log ...\SMSTS.LOG. LiteTouch   01/06/2015 09:54:30 0 (0x0000)

I see that it is unable to find the 'imagex.exe' file, where should this be located, and can I copy the file to the directory?

Any ideas?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Copy imagex.exe and wimgapi.dll (this may be optional, but I would still copy it) from the installation of ADK to the Tools\x86 and Tools\x64 directories in your deployment share.

For example (using 8.1 ADK instead of 8 ADK, folder names may be slightly different) the default installation on Server 2012 R2 would be "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kit\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM" for the 64-bit imagex.exe and wimgapi.dll files.  And "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kit\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\x86\DISM" for the 32-bit imagex.exe and wimgapi.dll files.

These files would be copied to the appropriate folders in C:\DeploymentShare\Tools\x64 and C:\DeploymentShare\Tools\x86.

This should resolve your problem.  For whatever reason, MDT sometimes does not place all the needed files into the Tools folder when you create a deployment share.